# Is Instrumental Variable Estimation using delayed inputs unbiased?

Tags: bias, unbiased-estimator, instrumental-variables

Assuming the following system:
$y(k) = \frac{B(z)}{A(z)} * u(k) + e(k)$
where e is zero-mean white noise and 
$A(z, θ) = 1 + a_1 z^{−1}  + a_2 z^{−2} ...$

and

$B(z, θ) = b_1 z^{−1}  + b_2 z^{−2} ...$

with the notiation that $\theta = [a_1, a_2, ..., a_{n_a}, b_1, ..., b_{n_b}]$

**is estimating $θ$ via the instrumental variable approach using delayed inputs asymptotically unbiased?**

My thought process why it should be:

I know that the instrumental variable approach using generated outputs by first estimating $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ via another method (let's say Least-Square) in a first experiment and then performing a second experiment (measuring $u_2$ and $y_2$) while simulating the output of the "new" system ($\hat{A}, \hat{B}$) omitting the noise which gives the instruments $x$. 
This method is asymptotically unbiased because the instruments $x$ are uncorrelated with the noise from the second experiment.

Following that logic, the delayed inputs ($u_2$) are also uncorrelated with the noise of the same experiment and thus the method should also be asymptotically unbiased. Is this correct?

I did not find an answer online after skimming a lot of papers and books on system identification